# Does C# spec permit casting from a ulong to an int? Monotouch gives a NumberOverflow

Tags: ios, c#-4.0, casting, xamarin.ios, boxing

I tested the following code in several environments

```
ulong c = 10000000000000000;  // Base 10
int w = (int) c;              // w should be 1874919424
```

The results are as follows:

```
VS2013 .NET 4.5         -   w = 1874919424
Xamarin (mono) Android  -   w = 1874919424
Xamarin (mono) iOS      -   number overflow
```

- Is this an issue that Xamarin should/will fix?  (e.g. the C# spec requires it)
- Does iOS / Objective C code support this casting?  (why isn't this working?)
- How can I work around this, without boxing or decreasing performance?

This method is used extensively in BouncyCastle encryption and I'm porting this to C# and want to make as few changes as necessary.

Comment: Have u checked the new data type in Xamarin: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/nativetypes/

Comment: @casillas I'm using the unified library.  Unsure if there are project settings that I need to inspect (project/workspace/simulator).  I'm new to this.  Also does x64 matter? I thought .NET would hide this from me.

Comment: @casillas That is a great article.  I suppose I need to somehow force the compiler to always use the Objective-C `int32_t`, and never use the `nint` type

Comment: @makerofthings7 `int32_t` is not particularly Objective-C, it is ANSI C defined in  <stdint.h>. Objective-C is a strict superset of "C".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If compiled *identically* then the behaviour should be identical on all platforms and that should not be related to unified/classic 32/64bits or `nint` support.

So make sure your iOS project is not build with the **Generate overflow checks** enabled.

Look for this in Project Options, Build, Compiler in Xamarin Studio or in the command-line options given to the compiler: `/checked`.

Comment: Holly smokes! That worked, I literally spent 18 hours tracking this down... THANK YOU